# Golang "Missing-cc"

Tags: golang, github, package

Пытаюсь загрузить пакет Golang для sqlite через *go get*, но выдает ошибку:

`cgo: exec /missing-cc: exec: "/missing-cc": file does not exist`

С многими другими пакетами тоже самое. В интернете ответа не нашел. Подскажите как решить, спасибо.
Работаю на винде

Comment: Вам надо установить Си компилятор в систему. Например, MinGW-w64.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!